# Dropping rows based on timeseries using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe with a time series data. The dates have been parsed.

```
data_path = "file.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(data_path, parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')
```

I have dates from 2008 to 2017 but I want to drop all rows from 2017. I know that I can select dates by doing this:

```
data.loc['2017']
```

...which selects all data from 2017. But, how can I drop rows based on .loc? If I try the code below, it gives an error:

```
data.drop(data.loc['2017'], axis=0)
```

> KeyError: "['centre' 'avg' 'id' 'age'] not found in axis"

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with test year by [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) for get all values if not `2017`:

```
df = data[data.index.year != 2017
```

Your solution:

```
df = data.drop(data.loc['2017'].index)
```

Comment: Absolute genius. That worked 100%. Which one do you recommend using though?

Comment: @user14903989 - Realy hard question, the best try in real data. My tip is first, but maybe I am wrong.